# Fix this without binding

Tags: javascript, bind

I want to convert `exec` function to `execAsync`

https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/blob/master/lib/bucket.js#L3257

I do this

```
couchbase.BucketImpl.LookupInBuilder.prototype.executeAsync = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.execute((error, result) => {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Sometimes I loose `this` and I don't want `bind` each time to instance `MutateInBuilder` 
Is it a way that automatically help me? I want always `this.execute` is `couchbase.BucketImpl.LookupInBuilder.prototype.execute`

Comment: So you really thought we would be looking through almost 4000 lines of code? Please provide a self contained minimal code example that illustrates the issue, inside the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange that you're overwriting the couchbase prototype... but as @trincot suggests, use fat arrow funtion:

```
couchbase.BucketImpl.LookupInBuilder.prototype.executeAsync = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.execute((error, result) => {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
};
```